# Projectile collide with a player issue?

Tags: python, pygame

Currently working on a 1v1 Pygame shooter and am having issues getting collisions to work properly. Bullets are supposed to be able to hit any player after 120 seconds of being alive. For some reason, the collisions trigger when no player has collided with a bullet and sometimes the collision doesn't trigger when the player visually collides with the bullet.

I was trying a lot of different things but I can't seem to get it correct. I'm debating on rewriting collision to be in the bullet class rather than the player class but I'll post some of my code.

```
def playerdeathevent(self):
        for bullet in bullet_list:
            if bullet.time_alive >= 120:
                # bullet_active_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
                bullet_active_list.add(bullet)
                # if self.PlayerHitboxRect.collidepoint([bullet.rect.x,bullet.rect.y]):
                #     draw_text(('Player ' + str(self.playernumber) + ' Died'), titlefont, WHITE, screen, 600, 700)
                #     pygame.sprite.Group.empty(bullet_list)
                #     return 'Destroyed'
                if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, bullet_active_list):
                    explode = Explosion(self.rect.x + 39, self.rect.y + 40)
                    explosion_group.add(explode)
                    collisionsound = mixer.Sound('Audio/EXPLODE-SFX1.wav')
                    collisionsound.play()
                    draw_text(('Player ' + str(self.playernumber) + ' Died'), titlefont, WHITE, screen, 600, 700)
                    pygame.sprite.Group.empty(bullet_list)
                    self.rect.x = self.rect.x + 1
                    self.rect.y = self.rect.y + 1
                    return 'Destroyed'
                else:
                    return 'Alive'
def player_score_count(self):
        if self.playernumber == 1:
            draw_text(str(self.playerLives), submenufont, WHITE, screen, 293, 55)
        elif self.playernumber == 2:
            draw_text(str(self.playerLives), submenufont, WHITE, screen, 1093, 55)
        if self.playerdeathevent() == 'Destroyed' and self.playerdeathevent() != 'Alive':
            if self.playerLives == 0:
                print('Game Over')
                draw_text('GAME OVER', titlefont, WHITE, screen, 600, 640)
                draw_text(('Player ' + str(self.playernumber) + ' Loses'), titlefont, WHITE, screen, 580, 700)
            else:
                self.playerLives = self.playerLives - 1
                print('HIT')
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) is wrong. First you need to identify the active bullets. [`empty()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.empty) the `bullet_active_list` *Group* and then add the currently active bullets. Then use the active bullets for collision detection:

```py
def playerdeathevent(self):

    bullet_active_list.empty()
    for bullet in bullet_list:
        bullet_active_list.add(bullet)

    # INDENTATION
    #<--|
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, bullet_active_list):
        explode = Explosion(self.rect.x + 39, self.rect.y + 40)
        explosion_group.add(explode)   
        # [...]
```

Comment: OH, that was such a simple solution it went over my head. Thanks so much!